# plotly offline map in r

Tags: r, plotly, openstreetmap

I was able to run a map offline with the leaflet library. I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same for the plotly library in r?

my code with leaflet:

```
# Set the working folder
setwd("C:/Users/user/Documents/mapTiles")

library(RgoogleMaps)
GetMapTiles(center = c(lat = 35.75, lon = 65.31), zoom = 10,
                               nTiles = c(20,20), type = "osm", tileDir= TRUE)

# Start serving working folder on port 8000 in demon mode
deamon_id <- servr::httd(port = 8002, daemon = TRUE)

# Plot with leaflet
library(leaflet)
m = leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://localhost:8002/osm/{z}_{x}_{y}.png")
m = m %>% leaflet::setView(65.31, 33.67,zoom = 10)
m

# Stop serving
servr::daemon_stop(deamon_id)
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Check out [this discussion on the topic](https://community.plotly.com/t/map-figure-with-open-street-map-and-pc-local-tiles/49813). The examples are for python, but should translate easily to R.

Comment: I already converted this code to R but it didn't work.